# Limit Joomla user login sessions

Tags: joomla, authentication, users

I am testing a Joomla installation for making a commercial website where you pay for accessing content. I just found out that it is possible to login from two different computers at the same time into Joomla and start browsing the restricted areas.

Is it somehow possible to restrict a login to only one user session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few plugins for this, but this is one I know works well:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/login-protection/15932

This simply restricts an account to "one-session" at a time, exactly as you're looking for.

Comment: Wonderful tool does a excellent job :)